# aiohttp.ClientSession() fails while requesting urls

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using asyncio in python to get data from a large number of urls.
Here I am trying to get data from yahoo.com 1000 times. And ~90% of the requests fail. Reducing the number of parallel requests reduces the % of fails. Trying to understand why this happens.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
could_not_fetch = []
```

fetching data from the url. almost 90% of them fail here.

```
async def fetch_page(url, session, id):
    try:
        async with session.get(url, timeout = 3) as res:
            html = await res.text()
            return html
    except:
        could_not_fetch.append(id)

async def process(id, url, session):
    html = await fetch_page(url, session,id)
```

using aiohttp.ClientSession() to request data from urls, also passing their index.

```
async def dispatch(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        coros = (process(id, url, session) for id, url in enumerate(urls))
        return await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

using asyncio to get data from yahoo.com 1000 times. if I reduce the number to 100, a much lesser ~ 10% of requests fail.

```
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop = loop.run_until_complete(dispatch(1000 * ['https://yahoo.com/']))
    print('could_not_fetch', len(could_not_fetch))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Trying to understand why these requests fail and how to rectify this while doing 1k requests at a time.

Comment: Your exception handling structure has some holes in it.  If the `async with` statement in `fetch_page` raises an exception, it will not be appended to failed_in_fetch even though that's what actually happened.  Instead it will return None back to `process`, which will put it in the failed_after_fetch list.  And nothing can ever get put in failed_before_fetch, since you silence all exceptions in fetch_page.  I suggest you clean this up and then see what happens.

Comment: @PaulCornelius thank you! Most of the requests were failing and not dropping the data. edited the question with the changes

Comment: What does it mean to “fail”? Does the request not send? Do you get a non-200 response? There’s a pretty good chance you’re being rated limited.

Comment: @dirn the except part if the code is executed. There are no error messages. so I am not sure if the request is sent or not.

Comment: increasing the timeout to 30 seconds solves the problem.